# Java regex issue with long strings

Tags: java, regex

I need help, I am working in a java regex, but I am having some issues.

This is my regex
`((?<=^)|(?<=(^|\b)((?<!(RUTA|KM|KMS)\s+)\w)))\p{Punct}(?=\w*)`
It is working as expected. Detect meaningful punctuation and keep it, and all other are deleted.

Test Input text

```
RUTA E-34 KMS 5.5 TEXTO 3.2 KM 4.9  KILOMETRO 8.4 RUTA E-35
```

Expected Output

```
RUTA E-34 KMS 5.5 TEXTO 3'.'2 KM 4.9  KILOMETRO 8'.'4 RUTA E-35
```

The issue is if I add to the excluded list `KILOMETRO` the regex stop working with the first occurrence, i get this output instead:

Output

```
RUTA E'-'34 KMS 5.5 TEXTO 3'.'2 KM 4.9  KILOMETRO 8.4 RUTA E-35
```

(it should not detect E-34)

I don´t know why a long word makes the regex to malfunction or how to fix it. Words to be excluded are dynamic, so eventually other long words can be added.

I appreciate any suggestions

UPDATE thanks to @WiktorStribiżew suggestion, final and working regex is

```
((?<=^)|(?<=(^|\b)((?<!(RUTA|KM|KMS|KILOMETRO)\s{1,20})\w)))\p{Punct}(?=\w*)
```

Comment: Please format the question nicely. See the formatting options (as icons) just above the question when you edit it.

Comment: See https://regex101.com/r/LXpIcA/1, it works with `KILOMETRO`, doesn't it? It is your regex, I just trimmed it a bit.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew yes, that change made the regex work! thanks a lot!

Comment: But I did not change it much, it is basically your regex, I replaced the `\s+` with `\s{1,100}` only to make it work online, it worked in your Java code, or was it due to `\s+`?